# Leap year function; how does this solution work?

Tags: javascript, equality, boolean-logic

The problem is this:

Given a year, report if it is a leap year.

The tricky thing here is that a leap year in the Gregorian calendar occurs:

```
on every year that is evenly divisible by 4
  except every year that is evenly divisible by 100
    unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400
```

My solution(that works) was this:

```
export const isLeap = (year) => {
    const yearModFour = (year % 4) === 0 
    const yearModHundred = (year % 100) === 0
    const yearModFourHundred = (year % 400) === 0 
    const isLeapYear = yearModFour === yearModHundred === yearModFourHundred
    return isLeapYear
}
```

I came to this conclusion because I miss read the logic as:

```
on every year that is evenly divisible by 4
  and also evenly divisible by 100
    and also evenly divisible by 400
```

My question is, why does this somehow work?

I'm not sure why I didn't use && operands, but then again it wouldn't have worked that way

Comment: It's more like `yearModFour && (!yearModHundred || yearModFourHundred)`

Comment: I think the OP is stating that his code works - which it does - but he doesn't understand why

Comment: or also `yearModFour && !(yearModHundred && !yearModFourHundred)`

Comment: or `new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() === 1;` then if the rules change in the year 2400, your code will survive :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give a technical answer.

Let A = divisible by 4, B = divisible by 100, C = divisible by 400. The definition if leap year is:

```
(A and (not B)) or C
```

But you wrote:

```
(A === B) === C
```

We need to ask whether these formulas are logically equivalent, for all possible consistent values of A, B, and C. We do not have to try all combinations of A, B, and C, because these formulas are NOT logically equivalent in general:

```
A  B  C   (A & !B)  (A & !B | C)    A==B   (A==B)==C
------------------------------------------------------
T  T  T     F            T          T        T
T  T  F     F            F          T        F 
T  F  T     T            T          F        F   x
T  F  F     T            T          F        T
F  T  T     F            T          F        F   x    
F  T  F     F            F          F        T   x
F  F  T     F            T          T        T 
F  F  F     F            F          T        F
```

HOWEVER, not all possible values of A, B, and C are consistent, as they depend on each other. Whenever C is true (divisible by 400) the others must be as well. Whenever B is true, A must be as well. So the only cases we have to consider are:

```
A  B  C   (A & !B)  (A & !B | C)    A==B   (A==B)==C
------------------------------------------------------
T  T  T     F            T          T        T
T  T  F     F            F          T        F 
T  F  F     T            T          F        T
F  F  F     F            F          T        F
```

These are the only four cases that are possible (TTT, TTF, TFF, and FFF). In each of these four cases, (A & !B | C) has the same truth value as (A==B)==C, so your code worked.

In general, the formulae are not equivalent to each other, but in this case, you were okay.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the predicate `yearModFour === yearModHundred === yearModFourHundred`, and list a few numbers that will lead to all possibilities.

For year 1, the predicate evaluates to:

```
(False === False) === False
             True === False
                 False
```

For year 4, the predicate evaluates to:

```
(True === False) === False
           False === False
                 True
```

For year 100, the predicate evalueates to:

```
(True === True) === False
           True === False
               False
```

For year 400, the predicate evaluates to:

```
(True === True) === True
           True === True
                True
```

Now that's all the possiblities and won't be any else here. This is because any number divisable by 400 are divisible by 100, 4, and 1; any divisable by 100 are so too by 4 and 1; and so on.

So your conclusion is not quite correct, as it implies logical "and" between all of the modulo operations.

Comment: `So your conclusion is not quite correct, as it implies logical "and" between all of the modulo operations.` but if it did, your example with `4` would be `false`, unless I misunderstood your sentence.

Comment: You might want to add why those 4 are all possibilities. Naively, 3 boolean variables would have 8 combinations.

Comment: @Bergi Okey-dokey.

Comment: I would think it was obvious ... %400 = true, then %100 and %4 can ONLY be true, and %100 true, then %4 can only be true, so it's blatantly clear why there are not 8 possibilities :p

Comment: @MatteoTassinari The example with 4 is correct according to the evaluation of JavaScript (ECMAScript) expressions. The quote is responding to the self-answer in the OP, not having anything to do with my examples.